NextJS v14 architecture to call a LLM
In a NextJS v14 application, I need to call a proxy API that interacts with an LLM. The API returns an NDJSON response, which needs to be processed using the ndjsonStream function from the can-ndjson-stream npm library.
I have a client component with a form that sends a server action containing the question to the LLM, and another client component to display the result.
I am unsure how to integrate these components effectively.
My server action calls the LLM proxy API, but I am uncertain where to place the ndjsonStream processing. Additionally, how do I send the processed stream back to the client component?

Not exactly sure what you're struggling with, but why not just use the same format most LLM APIs use (which is server-sent-events)? and use https://github.com/lukeed/fetch-event-stream/

I am dependent on the existing API. My concern, however, is more about the NextJS v14 architecture rather than how to receive the data from the API.

not sure what's the problem. you should post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

A solution to this problem is available on Vercel Github : https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/67501
